# how can I set a login prompt as soon as possible in the boot sequence?

Tags: login

I want my login prompt to come as soon as few necessary drivers are loaded. 
So for example once SPI driver is loaded, I will put the login prompt application just below SPI driver , and the CPU will execute this login application. Ultimately I will be having a fully running login prompt on the console just after loading of SPI drivers is over.

How can I set a login prompt as soon as possible in the boot sequence? 
How should I proceed?

Comment: are you sue to take the problem in the right order ? you should change your question to `how can I set a login prompt as soon as possible in the boot sequence`, because asked like this it's very unlikely that you get an answer

Comment: @Kiwy Kindly edit the title. Your suggestion is correct

Comment: What distribution are you on? You probably want to look at http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/ and `systemd` based systems for the fastest "prompting".

Answer (score 2):

If you want it AS SOON AS POSSIBLE, you ensure you have all that's necessary in your `initramfs` image to support this and add this kernel parameter to your bootloader:

```
init=/bin/login
```

That will get it up AS SOON AS IS POSSIBLE - if at all.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "all that's necessary in your initramfs image to support this"

Comment: is it mandatory to have initramfs if I want a login prompt? let's say I do not want to have any file system at all, can I have login prompt then, once linux boot?

Comment: It is mandatory to have `initramfs`. All thats necessary would be `login`'s dependencies.